# Валидатор для сравнения паролей Angular

Tags: angular

Незнаю как сравнить поля с паролями для функции валидатора,
ниже функция которая валидирует поля с паролями, но этот валидатор могу только на одно поле повешать а как сделать одинаковую функцию для двоих

```
 this.form = new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email], this.forbiddenEmails.bind(this)),
      'pass': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
      'conf_pass': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)],
        this.confirm_pass.bind(this))
    })

confirm_pass(control: FormControl): Promise<any>{

const val = this.form.value;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          if (control.value !== val.pass){
            resolve({confirm_pass: true});
          }else {
            resolve(null);
          }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить свой кастомный валидатор:

```
private passEqual() {
  return (group: FormGroup) => {
    return (!group.dirty || !group.touched) ||
            group.get('pass').value === group.get('conf_pass').value ?
               null : 
               { custom: 'пароли не совпадают' };
  }
}
```

И добавить в builder его вызов:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email], this.forbiddenEmails.bind(this)),
      'password': new FormGroup({
          'pass': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
          'conf_pass': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)],
    this.confirm_pass.bind(this))
       }, this.passEqual()),

    })
```

Comment: почему то выдает ошибку Cannot find control with name: 'pass' хотя такое поле было

Comment: formGroupName="password" добавьте родительского для блока паролей

Comment: `<div formGroupName="password"> .... <input formControlName="pass"/> <input formControlName="conf_pass"/> .... </div>`

Comment: благодарю, затупил=)